# Indefinite article with "or"

Tags: articles, usage

Do we need to use an indefinite article before each option while using **'or'** (as in the former case)?

> *"The point or state at which **a person or a company** breaks even."*
> *"The point or state at which **a person or company** breaks even."*

Or do we use it before the first option (as in the latter case)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use article 'the' with conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99590/how-to-use-article-the-with-conjunction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A person or company* creates the sense of a category to me, two things which should be treated as equivalents. *There is a cat or dog making noise outside* implies that you believe it's *definitely* one of those two things.

*A person or a company* feels softer I think, with less of a feeling of "the group consists of these things*, more like "here are two possible examples of what I'm talking about". It's a very subtle difference!

- *Would you like a coffee or tea?* (these are your two options, want one of them?)
- *Would you like a coffee or a tea?* (I'm offering these two things, but maybe I have others if you ask!)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to; and I'd prefer the second one with one **"a"**, unless you want to emphasize both of them, a "person" and a "company", in your sentence.